# update and return the new document mongodb angularjs 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

i fixed the returnNewDocument to true, but still have the old document, how can I fix this?

```
 public updateBestScore(scoreBD: ScoreBD, level: string): Promise<any> {
        return client.connect(url)
            .then(
            // Promesse tenue
            (db: any) => db.collection('BEST_SCORES').findOneAndUpdate(
                { "level": level.toLowerCase, "bestScore.username": scoreBD.usernameBD  },
                { $set: { "bestScore.$.score": scoreBD.score, "bestScore.$.username": scoreBD.usernamePlayer} },
                { returnNewDocument : true }
            )
                .then(
                (res: any) => {
                    db.close();
                    console.log("resultat : ", res);
                    if (res.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting === true) {
                        console.log("resultat apres findOneAndUpdate : ", res.value.bestScore);
                    }
                }),
            // Promesse rompue
            (err: any) => { throw "erreur"; });

    }
```

Comment: add some description about what you expected and problem that you faced with

Comment: i want to update my collection and return the new update collection. but the method still return the old collection before update

Comment: add comment to question